# Problema diseño responsive html

Tags: html, css, responsive, responsivo

El problema es que necesito hacer un diseño responsive a este código y hemos utilizado display:none para ocultar elementos del formato ordenador en tablet y móvil y funciona correctamente. Pero me oculta los elementos también en formato ordenador y no entiendo por qué pues creo que está todo correctamente enlazado. Inserto fotos para mostrar cómo se ve en móvil y ordenador. ¿Alguien tiene alguna solución?

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
 
<head>
  <title>DayDream Library</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=with, initial-scale=1">
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Ejemplo_clase_mejor - copia.css" />
  </head>

  <header>
    <div class="col-8 col-s-12">
    <img class="esconder_movil esconder_tablet foto_logo" src="logo.png" alt="logo biblioteca">
    <img class="esconder_ordenador esconder_tablet foto_logo_movil" src="logo.png" alt="logo biblioteca">
    <img class="esconder_ordenador esconder_movil foto_logo_tablet" src="logo.png" alt="logo biblioteca">
    </div>
    <h1>DayDream Library</h1>
     
    <p align="right">
         <div class="esconder_movil esconder_tablet col-4 col-s-12">
    <img id="icono_contador" src="contador.png"  alt= "icono contador"> &nbsp;
    <img id="icono_wishlist" src="corazon bueno.png"  alt= "icono wishlist libros"> &nbsp;
    <img class="icono2" src="usuario.png" alt= "icono perfil de usuario"> &nbsp; 
    <img  id="ingles" src="icono ingles.png"  alt= "icono cambio de idioma a inglés">
    </div>
    
        <div class="esconder_ordenador esconder_tablet col-4 col-s-12">
            <img class="icono_contador_movil" src="contador.png"  alt= "icono contador"> &nbsp;
            <img class="icono_wishlist_movil" src="corazon bueno.png"  alt= "icono wishlist libros"> &nbsp;
            <img class="icono2_movil" src="usuario.png" alt= "icono perfil de usuario"> &nbsp; 
            <img class="ingles_movil" src="icono ingles.png"  alt= "icono cambio de idioma a inglés">
        </div>
        <div class="esconder_ordenador esconder_movil col-4 col-s-12">
            <img class="icono_contador_tablet" src="contador.png"  alt= "icono contador"> &nbsp;
            <img class="icono_wishlist_tablet" src="corazon bueno.png" alt= "icono wishlist libros"> &nbsp;
            <img class="icono2_tablet" src="usuario.png"  alt= "icono perfil de usuario"> &nbsp; 
            <img class="ingles_tablet" src="icono ingles.png"  alt= "icono cambio de idioma a inglés">
        </div>
        <input class="icono" id="MenuDer" type="search" value="  Búsqueda" name="buscador">
    </p>  
</header>

</html>
```

[image: EN FORMATO MÓVIL]
[image: CSS1]
[image: CSS2]
[image: CSS3]
[image: CSS4]
[image: CSS5]
[image: CSS6]
[image: HTML1]

Comment: No pongas imagenes; pon texto. Nadie va a trabajar con imagenes para resolver el problema.

Comment: @CandidMoe es que no me dejaba insertar todo el código, sabes cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: No tienes que poner **todo** el código, sólo aquella parte donde está el problema. Mientras más código pongas, menos personas estarán dispuestas a ayudarte. Revisa este documento: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)